# Calculate value in the query by values from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g, inner-join

I have product table like this

```
PRODUCT_ID  PACK_SIZE   PACK_PRIZE

 3000           5       2.5

 3001           5       2.5

 3002           5       2.5

 3003           5       2.5
```

Order table

```
order_id     client_id 

75001   1024

75002   1033

75003   1030
```

ITEMS Table

```
ORDER_ID    PRODUCT_ID  NUMBER_ORDERED

 75001  3936    2

 75001  3557    5

 75001  3012    3

 75001  3236    4
```

Client Table

```
CLIENT_ID   LAST_NAME    STATUS

 1021    Smith          private

 1022    Williams       corporate

 1023    Browne         private

 1024    Tinsell        corporate
```

These are sample data I just added these just to show sample data.
I want to select top 2 private clients who has done the orders which are having higher values.

I have problem in selecting orders with max sold amount.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

In this I'm trying to get the Client IDS

```
 SELECT CLIENTS.CLIENT_ID
 FROM ORDERS
 INNER JOIN ITEMS ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID=ITEMS.ORDER_ID
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID =PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
 INNER JOIN CLIENTS ON ORDERS.CLIENT_ID = CLIENTS.CLIENT_ID
 WHERE ( )
```

In this i'm trying to select top 2 orders

```
 SELECT TOP 2 ORDERS.ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS
 INNER JOIN ITEMS ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID=ITEMS.ORDER_ID
 INNER JOIN PRODUCTS ON ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID =PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
 WHERE ((PRODUCTS.PACK_PRIZE/PRODUCTS.PACK_SIZE)*(ITEMS.NUMBER_ORDERED));
```

Gives me errors
FROM Key word not found where expected.

What I want to do is select the order ids from orders which are having highest total and which are not from same client, total should be calculated by finding the unit price by dividing pack_price from pack_size and multiplying it by number_ordered from the items table which is having the matching order id. The ordered clients should be corporate clients.

I'm using oracle 11g.

pack_prize is number pack_size is number 
number_ordered is number data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `top 2`.  Instead use `rownum` and a subquery:

```
WITH CTE as (
      SELECT ORDERS.ORDER_ID, PRODUCTS.PACK_PRIZE, PRODUCTS.PACK_SIZE, ITEMS.NUMBER_ORDERED
      FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN
           ITEMS
           ON ORDERS.ORDER_ID = ITEMS.ORDER_ID INNER JOIN
           PRODUCTS
           ON ITEMS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID
     )
SELECT ORDER_ID
FROM (SELECT CTE.*
      FROM CTE
      ORDER BY (PACK_PRIZE/PACK_SIZE) * NUMBER_ORDERED DESC
     ) t
WHERE rownum <= 2;
```

I'm guessing that the strange `where` expression is what you are using to determine the best rows.

Comment: It gives me the error sqlcommand not properly ended. and one more thing, how can connect this with my first query. Can you provide me with an answer without CTE, as I'm novice to CTE it's bit complicateing the situ.

Comment: @chathwind, cte is readable than a subquery. it is like subquery only. added missing bracket. to get client id, join with client table in the cte

Comment: @GordonLinoff It still gives not properly ended error. :(

Comment: @radar One more thing,the selected 2 orders from cte should be from corporate clients. How to achieve that? Could you kindly show how to join cte ?

Answer (score 0):

TOP does not work in oracle. You can use the virtual column `ROWNUM` or the function ROW_NUMBER() OVER() to get similar functionality.

Comment: Other than that can you find me a way to get the answer?